# KVM giving error "Error, Host does not support any virtualization options"

Tags: manjaro

I am running on Manjaro Linux and am trying to run a virtual machine under qemu and libvirt using virtual machine manager "virt-manager" I am running an Intel for virtualization, have VT/x enabled, and it shows it when I check it in the command line using `LC_ALL=C lscpu | grep Virtualization` and it outputs:

```
Virtualization: VT/x
```

I also checked the kernel with this: `zgrep CONFIG_KVM /proc/config.gz`
and the result includes this: `CONFIG_KVM_INTEL=m`

I also saw a solution of adding your user to the kvm and libvirt groups, but that did not work. I would change the `CPU Default` setting to copy Host CPU definition, but I cannot even create a virtual machine.

KVM gives the message "Error, Host does not support any virtualization options"

How am I able to get virtual machine manager to let me add virtual machines?

Comment: is virtualisation enabled in your machine's BIOS?   it's not uncommon for it to be disabled by default.    Also, what model CPU and brand/model of the PC or motherboard?

Comment: Yes it is, VT/x is enabled, Intel Core-i5 7th gen. I can pull up the exact type when I get a chance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just had the very same problem (on archlinux). the reason was dumb: I simply didn't have qemu installed, which I found out by looking at libvirtd logs.

That was very stupid and I lost an evening on this, so I'm writing it down for the next person getting bitten by this obtuse error message.

Comment: Thanks, yea i spent a few days then just gave up. I eventually realized qemu wasn’t installed, but wasn’t sure why.